# How to install Jlint-3.0 on ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: java, secure-coding

I tried installing jlint-3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 for static code analysis of java .class files. The error I got:

```
gcc -c -Wall -O2 -g antic.c
gcc -g -lz -o antic antic.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [antic] Error 1
```

How do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing libz (aka zlib). You can install that dependency like

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```